# How limit the detail rows to 10?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I follow [Ryan's tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) to add master-detail rows by Javascript:

```
def sheet_add_row_link(form_builder)
  link_to_function "Add" do |page|
    form_builder.fields_for :sheet_details, SheetDetail.new, :child_index => 'NEW_ROW' do |f|
      html = render(:partial => 'sheet_detail', :locals => { :df => f })
      page << "$('sheet_details').insert({ bottom: '#{escape_javascript(html)}'.replace(/NEW_ROW/g, new Date().getTime()) });"
    end
  end
end
```

How can I limit to maximum number of rows to 10, instead of unlimited?

Update, with detail partial code, `_sheet_detail.html.erb`:

```
<div class='sheet_detail'>      
    <div class='<%= 'detail_row_' + @view_row.to_s %>'>
      <div id='detail_model'> <%= df.select :model, models %> </div>
      <div id='detail_quantity'>  <%= df.text_field :quantity %> </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>     
</div>
```

if I put:

```
page << "if($$("sheet_detail").length < 5) {$('sheet_details').insert({ bottom: '#{escape_javascript(html)}'.replace(/NEW_ROW/g, new Date().getTime()) })};"
```

it returns error:

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon May 02 22:18:22 +0800 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  sample/app/helpers/sheets_helper.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kEND
...  page << "if($$("sheet_detail").length < 5) {$('sheet_detai...
                              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a conditional in your JavaScript that checks for the number of rows before calling `insert`:

```
page << "if(lessThanTenRows) { $('sheet_details').insert({ bottom: '#{escape_javascript(html)}'.replace(/NEW_ROW/g, new Date().getTime()) })};"
```

Since you are already using jQuery you can find the number of current rows by getting the length of a DOM query that checks the amount of rows (e.g. by a specific class used by the rows, etc.).

**Example**

```
var lessThanTenRows = $$("someRowSpecificClass").length < 10
```

`someRowSpecificClass` is a CSS rule you would define on each row (via `class=` in the HTML for each row).

I would try to find a way to make the resulting JavaScript more readable, but the essential part of the solution is counting the number of results you get from the DOM query.

Comment: How to tell what is `".someRowSpecificClass"`? Thanks!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I saw the `$` and thought you were using jQuery. I'll update my response to mirror what Prototype uses.

Comment: @ohho - I updated my answer to reflect Prototype's selectors. I believe $$ is the correct use to find elements via CSS classes (from the docs). Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @ohho - Your error concerns the use of double quotes in the JS statement. Since you're still in ruby at that point the double quotes messes up the ruby statement. Try escaping the double quotes (\") or using single quotes: `$$('sheet_detail')`

Comment: Changed to `page << "if($$('sheet_detail').length < 3) {$('sheet_details').insert...`, still no luck. I can add more than 3 rows.

Comment: @ohho - Are you sure `sheet_detail` is the class you should be checking for? You need to get the amount of rows that have been added. So each new row you create should have the same class as all the other rows. This will allow you to get the amount of rows that have been created. My point is, if `$$('sheet_detail').length` is always one or something then you're probably checking the wrong thing. Does `$$('sheet_detail').length` ever change (check via firebug or something)?

Comment: `_sheet_detail.html.erb` is the code get inserted and I am not sure which `div` should I check ...